# Can't set msDs attributes with Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Trying to set msDS-cloudExtensionAttribute1 with Powershell when it's an incorrect or not set value.

Unfortunately, it's not getting set. Not sure what's going on.

EDIT: Just noticed by manually updating the attribute that when I run a get command, it gets an incorrect value. Are there caching issues with powershell and these attributes?

```
$currUser = Get-ADUser $username -Properties * -server $domain | select employeeID, msDS-cloudExtensionAttribute1
$employeeID2 = $currUser.employeeID
$currUser | Set-ADUser -Clear msDS-cloudExtensionAttribute1
$currUser | Set-ADUser -Add  @{"msDS-cloudExtensionAttribute1" = $employeeID2 }
```

Comment: I would expect some errors running that. Anyway, I would remove this bit and try again; `| select employeeID, msDS-cloudExtensionAttribute1`.

Comment: "when I run a get command, it gets an incorrect value." - what command are you running, what value are you expecting, and what value do you actually get back?

Comment: @notjustme I've modified it as suggested, removed the second line, and set the variable on the last line to $currUser.employeeID instead of $employeeID2 and it's worked. 

I did do this early on and I'm sure it didn't at the time. One of those brick wall situations. Appreciated.